# vuejs unit test a component which has a child component

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuelidate

I want to test a TheLogin.vue component that has a child BaseInput.vue component. I tried the code below and also shallowMount but I keep getting the error below.

TheLogin.vue

```
<template>
   <section>
    <legend>
      Hello Login
    </legend>
   <BaseInput id="userName"></BaseInput>
   </section>
</template>

export default {
  name: 'TheLogin',
  data() {
    return {
      userName: null
      }
   }
}
```

TheLogin.spec.js

```
import TheLogin from '@/pages/login/TheLogin.vue';
import BaseInput from '@/components/ui/BaseInput.vue';
import { createLocalVue, mount } from '@vue/test-utils';

describe('TheLogin.vue', () => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue();
  localVue.use(BaseInput); // no luck

  it('renders the title', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(TheLogin, {
      localVue,
      // stubs: {BaseInput: true // no luck either
      // stubs: ['base-input']    // no luck again
    });
    expect(wrapper.find('legend').text()).toEqual(
      'Hello Login'
    );
  });
```

I import my base components in a separate file which I import into my main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
const components = {
   BaseInput: () => import('@/components/ui/BaseInput.vue'),
   BaseButton: () => import('@/components/ui/BaseButton.vue'),
   //et cetera
};
    
Object.entries(components).forEach(([name, component]) =>
   Vue.component(name, component)
);
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'userName' of undefined
```

**UPDATE**

Turned out it was Vuelidate causing the error (the code above was not complete). I also had in my script:

```
validations: {
    userName: {
      required,
      minLength: minLength(4)
    },
    password: {
      required,
      minLength: minLength(4)
    }
  }
```

I solved it by adding in my test:

```
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate';
import Vue from 'vue';
Vue.use(Vuelidate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to shallow mount the component without using localVue and setting `BaseInput` as a stub?

Something like:

```
import TheLogin from '@/pages/login/TheLogin.vue';
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';

describe('TheLogin.vue', () => {
  it('renders the title', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(TheLogin, {
      stubs: { BaseInput: true }
    });
    expect(wrapper.find('legend').text()).toEqual(
      'Hello Login'
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: thank, this would work, but I didn't need to stub the BaseInput, using shallowMount. The main reason is in my updated post.